# How can I make text background cover entire text?

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

I have this text definition:

```js
<Text fontSize="3rem"
      fontWeight="bold"
      textAlign="center"
      alignSelf="center"
      backgroundColor="dimgray">
      Jujutsu/Kadena-de-Mano
</Text>
```

But it renders with only part of the text covered by the background

[image]

How can I extend the background so that it covers all the text?